spring JSP errors resolve
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Message JSP file [/WEB-INF/views/error.jsp] not found
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
In the eclipse console showing the response error.
Unable to find the exact reason for this issue. Do you think anyone could fix it?

Check if this file exists under your project directory /webapp/WEB-INF/views: error.jsp, if not, create one.
